# In mysql user defined function how to set dynamic return data type

Tags: mysql, decimal, finance, mysql-function

In mysql user defined function how to set dynamic return data type based on function execution.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION financeNumberFormat(number double) RETURNS DECIMAL(10,5)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE decpoint int(10);

    SELECT c_maximum_decimal_values INTO decpoint
    FROM mst_xxx
    WHERE 1 LIMIT 1;    


    SET decpoint = FORMAT(number,decpoint); 

 RETURN (decpoint);
END
```

My output is coming like below.

```
financeNumberFormat(5.345)  
5.000
```

The decpoint may vary, so return value should be based on that decimal point. Is there a way to achieve it.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are talking about the returns data definition then no it's as coded.

Comment: What i want is to dynamically change the decimal point to be dynamic in the return value . RETURNS DECIMAL(10,5) . is that not possbile ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `DOUBLE` for financial data. Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `FORMAT` returns a string, since it can contain commas (thousands-separators).  So, you may as return `VARCHAR(99)`.  By the same token, you may as well feed in strings unless your numbers are really `DOUBLE`.

Note that going from `DECIMAL(m,n)` to `DOUBLE`, then rounding (via `FORMAT`)d to some number of decimal places is doing 2 roundings, one more than you really need.

Another note:  In *many* situations in MySQL (not all), a string containing numeric data is just as good as `DOUBLE` or `DECIMAL`.  (The notable exception is with `WHERE varchar_col = 1234` will fail to use `INDEX(varchar_col)`.)